# OSX emoji panel position

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, emoji

I want to present emoji panel and using `NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(nil)`. it works fine, but sometimes it appears at random place and i want it to be "constrained" to text field where I'm going to use it. Can i set frame of panel manually or do it in another way? thanks for help

Comment: Maybe you can set the frame in the preferences. Take a look at com.apple.CharacterPaletteIM.plist, `CVPerProcessWindowState`.

Answer (score 1):

It requires your text field to be the first responder.

You could make a text field the first responder by calling following method:

Swift:

```
textField.window?.makeFirstResponder(textField)
```

Objective-C:

```
[[textField window] makeFirstResponder:textField];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Apple says about `becomeFirstResponder`: "Use the `NSWindow` `makeFirstResponder:` method, not this method, to make an object the first responder. Never invoke this method directly.".

Comment: Thanks for an advice, I would change my answer.

Comment: I've done this and the character palette still shows up as a floating window. I've written a related question here in case you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138430/emoji-list-in-nspopover-on-macos-like-messages-app