# Emoji List in NSPopover on macOS like Messages App

Tags: macos, emoji, appkit, nspopover

I want to show an `NSPopover` in my Mac app that lists the emoji just like Apple's Messages app does like this:

[image: Messages Emoji Popover]

All I can figure out so far is that I can show the character palette in my app using this:

```
NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(nil)
```

But that shows the palette as a separate window like this: [image: macOS Character Palette]

Does anyone know how I can embed the character palette in an `NSPopover` and retrieve the selected emoji in my app (similar to how Apple does it in Messages)?

Answer (score 4):

Set your textView, textField, or any other view as the sender of `NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(_:)`.

```
NSApp.orderFrontCharacterPalette(self.textField)
```

Comment: how do you adjust the position?